# Find unique ways some people can seat on some chairs

Tags: python, permutation

I have two lists of people and seats. I want to find unique ways that they can seats om the chairs. For example for set of people and seats:

```
a= ["P1","P2","P3"]
b = ["S1","S2","S3"]
```

I am looking for something like this

```
[(('P1', 'S1'), ('P2', 'S2'), ('P3', 'S3')),
 (('P1', 'S1'), ('P2', 'S3'), ('P3', 'S2')),
 (('P1', 'S2'), ('P2', 'S1'), ('P3', 'S3')),
 (('P1', 'S2'), ('P2', 'S3'), ('P3', 'S1')),
 (('P1', 'S3'), ('P2', 'S1'), ('P3', 'S2')),
 (('P1', 'S3'), ('P2', 'S2'), ('P3', 'S1'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `itertools` module to generate all possible combinations of the seats and people, and then create a list of tuples containing each unique combination of people and seats.

```
import itertools

a = ["P1","P2","P3"]
b = ["S1","S2","S3"]

# Generate all possible permutations of the seats and people
seating_arrangements = list(itertools.permutations(b))

# Create a list of tuples containing each unique combination of people and seats
unique_combinations = []
for arrangement in seating_arrangements:
    combination = list(zip(a, arrangement))
    if combination not in unique_combinations:
        unique_combinations.append(combination)

print(unique_combinations)
```

Comment: You don't need the uniqueness check. The solution could just be: `[tuple(zip(a, perm)) for perm in permutations(b)]`